# Rails-MiniMagick open file from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, minimagick

Simple question that I am having trouble with.  I'm using MiniMagick and I want to open an image file from my controller that is stored in my assets/images file but not having luck.  I keep getting 'No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen'.   Here is what I have.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
def create
  source= MiniMagick::Image.open('/assets/images/background001.jgp')
end
```

Comment: I see the asset-pipeline tag.  Is this image found in /app/assets/images? or /public/assets ?

Comment: app/assets/images.  But i don't really care where it is so I can move it if it will work in public/assets

Comment: Modified my answer based on that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filename extension is transposed.  ;)

```
 /assets/images/background001.**jgp**  vs. **.jpg**
```

The leading / references the root of the machine.

Use.

`source= MiniMagick::Image.open('app/assets/images/background001.jpg')`

Comment: lol, silly typo on my part but I fixed it and still got the same error